# Dockerfile returned a non-zero code: 3221225781

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows, windows-server-2019

I have a newly installed Windows Server 2019 Standard. On this I have installed Docker according to these instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=Windows-Server. But if I now build the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:6.2.4-nanoserver-1809

RUN echo "Test"
```

Then I get the following output.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  816.9MB
Step 1/34 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:6.2.4-nanoserver-1809
 ---> b4b538f24815
Step 2/34 : RUN echo "Test"
 ---> Running in 6da2f5d19b12
The command 'cmd /S /C echo "Test"' returned a non-zero code: 3221225781
```

I suspect that the exit code means that some DLL is missing. Unfortunately I have no idea which one. It is also not the NanoServer because if I take any other base image I get the same error.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:3.5-20210112-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

RUN echo "Test"
```

I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance :-)

---

Update:

If I try to run a container an connect to it with that command:

```
docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:3.5-20210112-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 cmd.exe
```

I get the following error.

```
failed to resize tty, using default size
```

Unfortunately I don't get any output with docker logs so I guess the container doesn't start at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker returning exit code 3221225781 installing vc\_redist.x64.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60348640/docker-returning-exit-code-3221225781-installing-vc-redist-x64-exe)

Comment: This exit code is quite common in Windows-based docker images and means "missing libraries". Whatever library that `echo` command uses is missing inside the base image you provided.

Comment: The accepted answer in the mentioned comment refers to a base image being just an incomplete layer which lacks lots of libraries. I'm not much familiar with Windows-based docker images but I guess you'd be fine if you change your base image to something more complete.

Comment: It's not the image it's not running in any image. Also, I can run any other command and they all fail.

Comment: Have you enabled/switched to Docker Windows containers? It might be you are trying to build a Linux image (because that is the default). If you right click on the Docker icon and click on the "Switch to Windows Containers" and restart whatever shell you are using and try again it will work. 
Building your image worked for me and I got the echoed test :)

Comment: I am on Windows Server there are only Windows images :-) There is also no Docker Desktop.

Comment: oh sorry missed the Windows Server part :(